# Debian Server Login Error

Tags: debian, login

Forgot password, booted into root recovery to reset root password.

Now any other userid login produces the message "The system is going down for reboot on . . .", a pause, then "Login incorrect".

Running 3.2.60-1

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the boot proces isn't complete then the file /etc/nologin exists to stop users from completing the logon proces. Make sure the boot proces is complete or that the system isn't in maintenance mode.